# Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "imagePath" because it is not an "own property" of its parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

i cant get my saved data from my product seeder to the store correctly

it looks like this https://prnt.sc/t10v00

and i want the image and the titles from the data i have come to the page

and in my terminal says ///// Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "title" because it is not an "own property" of its parent

```
{{# each products}}

<div class="row">
{{# each this}}

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="{{this.imagePath}}" alt="..." class = "img-responsive">
<div class="caption">
<h3 align="center">{{this.title}}</h3>
<p class="description">{{this.description}}</p>
    <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="price pull-left">€{{this.price}}<ahref="#" style="float:right"class="btn btn-primary pull-right" role="button">Add cart</a> </div>

     </div>
</div>

</div>

{{/each}}

</div>

{{/each}}


index.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Product = require('../models/product');
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 Product.find(function(err, docs) {
var productChunks = [];
var chunkSize = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
  productChunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
}
res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping Cart', products: productChunks });
 });
});

module.exports = router;
```

anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

```
"express-handlebars": "^3.0.0"
```

Used this version.
It worked.
It was giving same output for newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

Follow given bellow syntax:

```
dbName.find({}).lean()
  // execute query
  .exec(function(error, body) {
    //Execute you code
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
const Handlebars = require('handlebars');
const expressHandlebars=require('express-handlebars');
const { allowInsecurePrototypeAccess } = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access');


// view engine setup
app.engine('.hbs', expressHandlebars({ handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars) ,defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs'}));
//app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    I've added the following code and it's working fine. You need to add the runtimeoptions here. 
    const {engine} =  require('express-handlebars');
      
        
    app.engine('.hbs', engine({
            defaultLayout: 'main', 
            extname: 'hbs',
            runtimeOptions: {
                allowProtoPropertiesByDefault: true,
                allowProtoMethodsByDefault: true
            }
          }));
    app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

I have used the above code to implement the .hbs template engine.
```